# Android Firebase - Remove listeners from Task<T>

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I defined this method, in `MyActivity` class that allow me to download in memory some data from a `Firebase` storage.

```
public void submitDownload() {
    Task<byte[]> downloadTask=FirebaseStorage.getInstance.
            getReference(DATA_PATH_TO_DOWNLOAD).getBytes(MAX_BYTES);

    isTaskActive=true;
    //remove eventually a previous callback from the handler
    timeoutHandler.removeCallbacks(timeoutCallback);

    downloadTask.addOnSuccessListener(MyActivity.this, onSuccessListener);
    downloadTask.addOnFailureListener(MyActivity.this, onFailureListener);
    timeoutHandler.postDelayed(timeoutCallback, 5000);
}
```

This is, instead, the `onCreate()` method:

```
protected void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    onSuccessListener=new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
            if(isTaskActive) {
                isTaskActive=false;
                Log.d("DOWNLOAD_TASK", "SUCCESS");
            }
        }
    };

    onFailureListener=new OnFailureListener() {
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            if(isTaskActive) {
                isTaskActive=false;
                Log.d("DOWNLOAD_TASK", "FAILURE");
            }
        }
    };

    timeoutHandler=new Handler();
    timeoutCallback=new Runnable() {
        public voi run() {
            if(isTaskActive) {
                isTaskActive=false;
                Log.d("DOWNLOAD_TASK", "TIMEOUT");
                submitDownload(); //retry download
            }
        }
    };

    submitDownload();
}
```

Obviously, `onSuccessListener`, `onFailureListener`, `timeoutHandler`, `timeoutCallback` and `isTaskActive` are instance variable.

As you can see in the `run()` method defined in `timeoutCallback`, in addition to a log message, is also called the `sumbitDownload()`. Pratically, if a timeout occurs and the task is still active, a new download is started.

Now, imagine this scenario.
When Activity is created, a download task is started. Suppose that `downloadTask` doesn't complete, and neither `onSuccessListener` nor `onFailureListener` are called, but timeout occurs. So, from the `run()` method of `timeoutCallback` a new download is started.
Now, what happens to the previous `downloadTask`? Is it canceled? Is it replaced by the current task? or does it continue to be active and potentially could trigger its attached listeners?

If the latter question is true, how to remove the listeners from a `Task<T>` object?
Does the `getResult()` method, however, complete (i.e finish) the task?